# How do I use PHP to write multiple nodes of the same name to an XML file?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to use my PHP to take input from a form and write it to an XML file. It works fine for the unique fields, but there's one field that can be inputted 4 times.

When more than one is entered, only the last one is written to the XML file.

My PHP:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['ok'])){
            $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
            $xml->load("../Players.xml");

            $rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("site")->item(0);

            $entryTag = $xml->createElement("entry");

            $nameTag = $xml->createElement("name",$_REQUEST['name']);
            $countryTag = $xml->createElement("country",$_REQUEST['country']);
            $memTag = $xml->createElement("mem",$_REQUEST['mem']);

            $entryTag->appendChild($nameTag);
            $entryTag->appendChild($countryTag);
            $entryTag->appendChild($memTag);

            $rootTag->appendChild($entryTag);
            $xml->save("../Players.xml");

       }
?>
```

Form:

```
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="text" name="country"/>
            <input type="text" name="mem"/>
            <input type="text" name="mem"/>
            <input type="text" name="mem"/>
            <input type="text" name="mem"/>
            <input type="submit" name="ok"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: `name="mem[]"` will give you an array entry in `$_POST`. i.e. `$_POST['mem'][0]` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, just by several pairs of instrucntions similar to

```
$memTag = $xml->createElement("mem",$_REQUEST['mem']);
$entryTag->appendChild($memTag);
```

The result is supposed to be as several appended nodes, like:

```
<entry>
    <mem>bla-bla</mem>
    <mem>bla123</mem>
</entry>
```

But... How come the parameters are directly in $_REQUEST ?
And did you check how many parameters with name 'mem' are sent from the browser?

Comment: I followed an online video. If you could explain to me what's wrong with that I'd really appreciate it. I understand pretty much everything there except for the $_REQUEST bit. Still just a bit new to this stuff.

Comment: $_REQUEST is an associative array that by default contains the arrays $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. Those arrays contain (or not contain, it depends...) some data sent: $_COOKIE contains cookies (if any), $_GET contains parameters sent using get-method request, $_POST contains parameters sent if the request was sent via post method.

Comment: you can get more information at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: but still I bet you have only one 'mem' sent from browser (I think the last listed), not four.

Comment: Alright, that's useful information, but I'm still not sure why what I did was wrong there. 

Also, tried to do what you said, but it did not work.

Put in several pairs, ended up similar to last time. Just instead of it only saying the last input, it says the last input 4 times. It sounds like you have a point with only one "mem" being sent from the browser. Not sure how I'd go about fixing that, I mean I have four inputs. Kinda thought that'd count them all as unique I guess.

Comment: Name the parameters differently, like <input type="text" name="mem1"/><input type="text" name="mem2"/>, etc. Then (in the beginning of index.php) try to var_dump($_POST). You should see your four mems there. By the way I am sorry to disinform you: $_REQUEST contain not arrays but the contents of those other arrays. So your $_REQUEST['mem'] should work. I prefer to use those arrays separately. Sorry again. And now use in your code $_REQUEST['mem1'], $_REQUEST['mem2'], and so on.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the very late reply. Your solution ended up working, and in hindsight was kind of obvious but hey, sometimes that happens. Just gave them all unique names and everythings working good now.